# How to Set BlackOutDates for Multiple Months in WPF DateTimePick

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, datetimepicker

I need to set BlackOutDates for multiple months.

For example, upon selection of month ( i.e January 2014 ) , I want to show only certain Blackout dates. on the otherhand, For febraury, I want to show some other black out dates those were not the same as January.

But I can't find any property in WPF DateTimePick which can explicitly returns "months" those were bound to DateTimePick control at the time of List binding using ViewModel.

Is there any way, to set explicit BlackOutDays for each month.

Regards
Usman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to directly bind the BlackOutDates collection. Instead a helper class will do the magic. Usually attached properties will be used to handle this scenario. In the callback of property do manual mapping of BlackoutDates. A detail explanation is given in below link.

http://wpfplayground.com/2014/07/28/wpf-datepicker-blackoutdates-data-binding/

To get notification from date picker when Month is changed, use DisplayDate property. Bind this property in two way. And you can update your black out date collection on property changed.

```
    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "DisplayDate")
        {
            BlackOutDates = new List<DateTime> { DisplayDate.Date.AddDays(randm.Next(1, 5)), DisplayDate.AddDays(randm.Next(1, 5)) };
        }
    }
```

Comment: but i want to pupulate these blackout dates dynamically using ViewModel not hardcoding from XAML.
How would it be possible to bind the Property in ViewModel with XAML BlackOutDates

Comment: Could you please write complete XAML, as it is not compiling and saysing that "local" is not valid here. Moerover, it is saying DisplayDate Property not defined in the ViewModel.

Comment: Moreover, I also would like to see how OnPropertyChanged Event can be registered? How it would get callback when it is not being added or registered.

Comment: https://db.tt/X3vvCGiN You should download sample from the link. Accept it as answer if it is working.

Comment: @Jawahar your above dropbox link is dead